# jquery replace label name with a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors, replace

```
$("label[for='c1pick'] .ui-btn-text").html($("#introdukt").val())
```

I would like to replace c1pick and #introdukta with variables

Tried the first one the following way:

```
 whichone="c1pick" 
$("label[for=whichone] .ui-btn-text").html($("#introdukt").val())
```

but it doesnot work.

Is there a way? How to replace #introdukt reference with a variable, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("label[for=whichone] .ui-btn-text")
```

supposed to be

```
$("label[for=" + whichone + "] .ui-btn-text")
```

This selector

```
$("label[for=whichone]
```

tries to select this label `<label for="whichone"`

When you append the variable

`$("label[for=" + whichone + "]` it first replaces the variable and then tries to select the element.

**Code**

```
var whichone="c1pick",
    intro = "introdukt";

$("label[for=" + whichone + "] .ui-btn-text").html($("#" + intro).val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var whichone = "c1pick";
var intro = "introdukt";
$("label[for='" + whichone + "'] .ui-btn-text").html($("#" + intro ).val());
```